# Using MathJax to add element to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am trying to dynamically create an element then do some processing on it. I was trying to use MathJax on that newly created element but I can't pull MathJax.Hub.getAllJax on it.

I typed this in the console to test things out: (MathOutput1 is defined in the HTML)

```
MathJax.HTML.addElement(document.body, "div", {id: "blah"}, ['` `']);
<div id=​"blah">​` `​</div>​
MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("blah");
[]
MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("MathOutput1")
[Object]
```

Is there a way I can dynamically create an element that I can act on?

I did confirm that the div element blah was added to the dom (at least according to chrome) ""

Thanks :)

Comment: I could be wrong, but you may have to typeset the element before you can retrieve it. Something like `MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, getElementById('blah')]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that [MathJax operates asynchronously](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/synchronize.html), and you're trying to access the new element before the `MathJax.Hub` routines are fully finished.

To get around this, you can put your call to `MathJax.Hub.getAllJax()` in a callback function on the `Hub`'s *callback queue*:

```
function showBlahElement () {
    console.log(MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("blah"));
}

MathJax.HTML.addElement(document.body, "div", {id: "blah"}, ['$$a=b$$']);
MathJax.Hub.Queue(showBlahElement);
```

Or, you can register a *signal listener* that will get triggered whenever a certain event happens (in this case, whenever new math is typeset):

```
MathJax.Hub.Register.MessageHook("New Math", function (message) {
  console.log(MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("blah"));
});

MathJax.HTML.addElement(document.body, "div", {id: "blah"}, ['$$a=b$$']);
```

For more information, see the [API docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/api/index.html).

Comment: With the latest version of MathJax anyway, you'll need to insert another line to the first snippet:
`MathJax.HTML.addElement(...);`
`MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "blah"]);`
`MathJax.Hub.Queue(showBlahElement);`
Without the `Typeset` command, getAllJax returns an empty array. Try it out: https://codepen.io/jlidbeck/pen/qmjEwa?editors=1010